# Twilio - forward to different phone numbers per call not simultaneously

Tags: php, twilio

Is there a way in PHP to forward to multiple numbers in a rotation per call.  I understand that you can use the  verb to place multiple numbers to call at the same time.

How about?

- Call 1 goes to Company A
- Call 2 goes to Company B
- Call 3 goes to Company A
- Call 4 goes to Company B
- Call 5 goes to Company A

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think you're best bet would be to maintain a counter that your PHP file increments each time it runs.  When the counter gets to 4, the PHP page would simply reset it to 0.

If the list of numbers you need to call is static you could just put them into an array and the counter would serve as the array index.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may also want to consider adding in a script to ask them to press 1 to answer the call. That way if they are not available the script can continue onto the next person.

Comment: Good point.  Doing this would account for answering machines picking up the call.

Comment: @devin-rader Thanks, that's what I will do!  They are static, so thanks for the array tip!  You're right about voicemail picking up.

Comment: @stevendstanton Thanks for the "press 1" tip!  Great way to salvage a call.